# How to show this converges in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

$A_n(s)$ is a sequence of convex random functions defined on an open set $S\in \mathbb{R}^p$ which converges in probability to some $A(s)$ for each $s$. I'm trying to show that $\sup_{s\in K} \big| A_n(s)-A(s) \big|\stackrel{P}{\to} 0$ for $K\subset S$ compact.

I think I could use the fact that since $K$ is compact, then $\sup_{s\in K} \big| A_n(s)-A(s) \big| > \epsilon$ is an event contained in $\bigcup_{s\in K} \left\{\big| A_n(s)-A(s) \big| > \epsilon\right\}$ (since continuous functions reach their supremums on compact sets). But after that, I'm stuck because I can't see how to show the probability of $\bigcup_{s\in K} \left\{\big| A_n(s)-A(s) \big| > \epsilon\right\}$ goes to $0$.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are they continuous AND convex?

Comment: Convex functions are continuous.

Comment: @Glassjawed No, in general, this is not correct. Only convex functions on finite-dimensional spaces are continuous (more precisely, they are continuous in the interior of the domain).

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah I was just thinking in $\mathbb{R}^p$. I can't think of a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ off the top of my head though.

Also any suggestions for how to go about this problem?

Comment: This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126142/uniform-convergence-of-sequence-of-convex-functions) might be helpful; there it is proved that pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence on compact sets if the functions are convex (and continuous).