# Counterexample to Uniform Convergence of Convex Functions

Tags: real-analysis

It is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126142/uniform-convergence-of-sequence-of-convex-functions) that if a sequence $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ of convex continuous functions converges pointwise to a continuous function $f$, then the convergence is in fact uniform.

The answers given seem me to be correct proofs of the statement, however I was able to construct a counterexample pretty easily. Consider the functions

\begin{equation*}
 f_n = \begin{cases} -nx, & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac1n, \\
-2 + nx,  &\text{if } \frac1n \leq x \leq \frac2n,\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
It's clear that $f_n$ is convex and continuous, and moreover converges pointwise to $f \equiv 0$. However, the convergence is not uniform, since $\sup |f_n| = 1$.

I'm not sure whether there's I overlooked something when constructing this counterexample or the original statement about uniform convergence of convex functions is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try plotting your functions, are they actually convex? (Hint: you need to specify the domain of your $f_n$)

Comment: Ah, I made a silly mistake! Thanks.